MAUI routing in the Shell
I'm trying to setup some routing on shell items in a Maui application as there appears to be a consensus that this is the correct thing to do.
My routes are getting added dynamically as I'm requesting remote data to decide what options should be present
This registers correctly
Shell.Current.Items.Add(new ShellContent()
{
                Title = server.ServerName,
                Route = $"{this.SystemConnection.Name}_{server.ServerName}",
                ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(() => new ServerHomePage(new ServerViewModel(this.client, server)))
});

and then I can navigate to it with this
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"///{this.SystemConnection.Name}_{details.ServerName}");

As soon as I try and make the route hierarchical with
Route = $"{this.SystemConnection.Name}/{server.ServerName}"

The route can no longer be found regardless of the route I pass to GoToAsync.
Is it possible to add hierarchical routes programmatically?

You can register the parent route in the FlyoutItem and then register the child route in the ShellContent. Such as:
FlyoutItem flyoutItem = new FlyoutItem()
{
    Title = "test",
    Route = $"{this.SystemConnection.Name}",

};
flyoutItem.Items.Add(new ShellContent()
{
    Title = "hello",
    Route = $"{server.ServerName}",,
    ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(() => new NewPage2())

});
Shell.Current.Items.Add(flyoutItem);

And then navigate to it by:
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"///{this.SystemConnection.Name}/{details.ServerName}");

=========================

What if I then want to register another route from the child routed?
Along the lines of System/Server/Settings

You can regist the Settings route dynamically.
Routing.RegisterRoute($"{this.SystemConnection.Name}/{details.ServerName}/{SettingName}", typeof(SettingNamePage));

And then you can navigate to it by:
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"///{this.SystemConnection.Name}/{details.ServerName}/{SettingName}");

In addition, if the details.ServerName page is displayed now, you can navigate from details.ServerName page to SettingName Page with await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{SettingName}"); directly.
And the route /SystemName/Settings/ServerName/Settings you used, I can't understand the first Settings. If it's a contentpage, you can add and regist it following the code above.
Note: The root route (SystemName) is a flyoutitem. And all of its child route should be a contentpage.
=============================
The full code:
private void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
       FlyoutItem flyoutItem = new FlyoutItem()
       {
           Title = "test",
           Route = "App"

       };
       flyoutItem.Items.Add(new ShellContent()
       {
           Title = "NewPage2",
           Route = "Newpage2",
           ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(() => new NewPage2())

       });
     flyoutItem.Items.Add(new ShellContent()
     {
         Title = "NewPage1",
         Route = "Newpage1",
         ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(() => new NewPage1())

     });
     Shell.Current.Items.Add(flyoutItem);
     Routing.RegisterRoute("App/NewPage1/NewPage3", typeof(NewPage3));
 }

And then navigate from MainPage to the NewPage3:
Shell.Current.GoToAsync("///App/Newpage1/NewPage3");

The result image:

If you set the Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Flyout", when you click the hamburger menu, you will see:

And when you click the test item, you will see:


What if I then want to register another route from the child routed? Along the lines of System/Server/Settings

It appears I should be able to add more items and set the route as serverName/settings and while that appears to work in terms of getting it accepted if I then try and navigate using the UI I see it fail with a proposed route of /SystemName/Settings/ServerName/Settings

Please check the update part in my answer. @Saurbaum

I think what you are saying is that it's not actually possible to register multi level routes as shell content and you have to instead setup the top level then add the registration for them separately with RegisterRoute.

I can't understand the first Settings in this route ( /SystemName/Settings/ServerName/Settings) either. I appeared when I did a shell navigation having attempted to register /SystemName/ServerName/Settings using the route on shell content

I tested my code in the default maui app project template and it worked well. Can you show your full code? @Saurbaum

I have added my full code and the result image. You can check it. @Saurbaum

So it can only be done via register route so must also work with dependency injection I can't put a specific object in like with the Shell Content route?

Sorry for that I can't understand what you want clearcly.@Saurbaum

Routing.RegisterRoute("App/NewPage1/NewPage3", typeof(NewPage3)); Now if I want to pass specific variables to NewPage3 or more likely its ViewModel, because this is registered by type, I can't so it MUST use dependency injection for the object creation?

Please refer to the official document about passing data in maui shell navigation. @Saurbaum
